# Should you do 20*19*18*6 because you could compete in six different order of competing the three positions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Question: A company is selecting its president, vice president, and treasurer from 20 candidates. In how many ways can this be accomplished?

Should you do $20*19*18*6$ because you could compete in six different ways?

P VP T

20* 19 *18

P T VP

20* 19 *18

T P VP

20* 19 *18

T VP T

20* 19 *18

VP T P

20* 19 *18

VP P T

add it up

If you equate this with the fundamental counting principle or the multiplication/choice method you assume you have 20 people running for president times 19 running for vice president times 18 people running for treasurer, but you equally can have 20 for treasurer, 19 for vice-president, and 18 for president if you're competing backwards by rank.

I understand you don't use combinations formula on this problem.

Permutations says this is Permutations(20,3) which is $20*19*18$.

Comment: The answer is $20\times 19\times 18$ which is the same answer as $\binom{20}{3}\times 3!$.  You only need to multiply by $3!$ if you do not already know who is getting which role specifically.  Picking person A to be president, person B for vice president and person C for treasurer should be considered the same result as picking person C to be treasurer, person B to be vice president and person A to be president.  In both of these, the people doing the tasks is the same.  The order in which you made these decisions does not matter.

Comment: Yes, the solution is $20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18$ and is very simple to figure out this, since the first time you select one of the three out of $20$ people, then only $19$ people remain and you can select the second candidate, and finally one out of $18$. Now, it doesn't matter if you choose the president first, its vice or the treasurer... remember that the order of the elements does not count in a set (a set whose cardinality is equal to three, in this case).